# I would like to select a range in a column only until a certain word/character is found

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in setting a range to a variable. Basically, I have a column with an "if" formula in it. The results in the formula returns either a "" or a number. Here is what I have currently. This selects all the rows since it "finds" the "" in the formula of the entire column.

```
Set rngEnd = wkLS.Columns(cLS).Find("").Offset(-1, 0)
```

How do I select only the range that contains numbers considering that the "" will only show up at the row after the last cell with a number?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if I don't understand correctly, but if the "" cell is the last of the row, then why not going with last row? ie cells(rows.count... or usedrange.rows.count-1

Answer (score 0):

Your way or questioning is not the clearer I could see...
Supposing that I understood what you want to ask, try this, please. The code may  look more complicated than it should, because I do not know how `cLS` variable has been declared. If it would be a `Long`, the code would be simpler. But it can be a string `"A:A"`...

In case that you need the range from the first row of the column up to the first empty row (using `Find`):

```
Set rngEnd = wkLS.Range(wkLS.Columns(cLS).Cells(1, 1).Address, wkLS.Columns(cLS).Find("").Offset(-1, 0).Address)
Debug.Print rngEnd.Address
```

If you need the range from the first row of the column up to the last empty row:

```
Set rngEnd = wkLS.Range(wkLS.Columns(cLS).Cells(1, 1).Address, wkLS.Cells(wkLS.Cells(wkLS.Rows.count, wkLS.Columns(cLS).Column).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Address)
```

If you need a discontinuous range containing only the cells not being empty, up to the last empty row, but supposing that such empty cells exist, please use the next code:

```
Dim wkLS As Worksheet, rngEnd As Range, cLS As Long
Set wkLS = ActiveSheet: cLS = 1 'for A:A column, change for yours
Dim c As Range, finalRange As Range
Set rngEnd = wkLS.Range(wkLS.Columns(cLS).Cells(1, 1).Address, _
            wkLS.Cells(wkLS.Cells(wkLS.Rows.count, wkLS.Columns(cLS).Column).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Address)
        For Each c In rngEnd.Cells
            If c.Value <> "" Then
                If finalRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set finalRange = c
                Else
                    Set finalRange = Union(finalRange, c)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Debug.Print finalRange.Cells.count, finalRange.Address
```